# Shopify Dev: How I can control the box shadow color in schema?

Tags: css, json, shopify, shopify-template

I want to control the box shadow color in **shopify schema** by using the theme customizer.

**Here is my code :**

```
.test {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px rgba({{ section.settings.example_shadow }}, 0.1);
}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Example Shcema",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "example_shadow",
      "label": "Shadow Color",
      "default": "#000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

when I submit this code it show me this **error message :**

> "default must be a CSS color"

this problem it come from the **"default": "#000000"**

> my question is how I can convert the default hex color into rgb
> color???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default liquid tag `color_to_rgb` to convert a color to rgb color,
eg.

```
{{ '#7ab55c' | color_to_rgb }}
```

Reade more about color filters [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/color-filters)

Answer (score 0):

Please use `color_modify: 'alpha', 0.1` i was create example than answer too you.

```html
.test {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px {{ section.settings.example_shadow | color_modify: 'alpha', 0.1 }}
}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Example Shcema",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "example_shadow",
      "label": "Shadow Color",
      "default": "#000000"
    }
  ]
}
```